# Find SQL routines referencing not existing objects

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, dmv

When I am deprecating/deleting legacy SQL objects (stored procedures, functions, views, tables) I need to perform time consuming searches to ensure that the deletion is not going to break some existing functionality.

In many cases, when a stored procedure (for example) is referring a table (for example) that does not exist, it means that this is some legacy code that is not working now and can be dropped.

So, is there any system views, that I can query to find SQL routines that are referring not existing objects?

Comment: Check this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/askjay/2012/07/22/finding-missing-dependencies/

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL Search from redgate? It is 100% free and can search anything on your server. The above link is far simpler but searching the database should not be all that time consuming.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, I know it. By time consuming I mean that I am searching across asp files, rdls files, SSIS packages and others ... and the worse is there might be some customizations on the clients sites, so I need to check their folders, too.

Comment: Well if you have ad hoc queries in your code or on a client system then I don't see how this would help much. But at least now you know a good way to find them.

Comment: another approach might be a *visual studio database project*. Such a project is created automatically out of an exisiting database. Each object lives in a dedicated file. VS will then "compile" the solution and will point to any error. This allows you to "test" your changes to the schema before you apply them to the database.

Comment: @arunes thanks for the link, I've learned something new today :-)